# Padding between widgets that was set by tkinter's .grid() method, even though I didn't set it

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried place widgets by .grid() method, and when I place RadioButtons on different row - I saw that there padding on different row, also between them.

This is what I talking about (I point paddings that I noticed):
[image]

And there my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from string import hexdigits
from tkinter import ttk
from random import choices

color_hex = '#C91212'

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Main window')
        self.tool = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        self.topmenu = TopMenu(self)
        self.topmenu.pack()

class TopMenu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master: MainWindow):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.root = master
        ttk.Label(self, text="Hex color:").grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.symbol_entry_text = tk.StringVar(value=color_hex)
        self.symbol_entry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.symbol_entry_text)
        self.symbol_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        ttk.Button(self, text='Random').grid(column=3, row=0)
        ttk.Button(self, text='Load').grid(column=4, row=0)
        ttk.Button(self, text='Save').grid(column=5, row=0)

        self.c = tk.Canvas(self, width=21, height=21, highlightthickness=0, bg=color_hex)
        self.c.grid(column=2, row=0)
        
        ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Pencil', value=0, variable=self.root.tool).grid(row=1, column=0)
        ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Floodfill', value=1, variable=self.root.tool).grid(row=1, column=1)
        ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Eyedropper', value=2, variable=self.root.tool).grid(row=1, column=2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainWindow()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with your code, The thing here is that the color `Canvas` and the `Eyedropper` radio box is in the same column (`column=2`), that means the column width will we same for the both element.

Now there are some ways to get the window as you want

For this type of design

[image]

You can change the coulmnspan of `Eyedropper` radio button to `2` it means that now the radio button will we in two column.

```
ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Eyedropper', value=2, variable=self.root.tool).grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2)
```

Full code

```
import tkinter as tk
from string import hexdigits
from tkinter import ttk
from random import choices

color_hex = '#C91212'

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Main window')
        self.tool = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        self.topmenu = TopMenu(self)
        self.topmenu.pack()

class TopMenu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master: MainWindow):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.root = master
        ttk.Label(self, text="Hex color:").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)

        self.symbol_entry_text = tk.StringVar(value=color_hex)
        self.symbol_entry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.symbol_entry_text)
        self.symbol_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        ttk.Button(self, text='Random').grid(column=3, row=0, padx=10)
        ttk.Button(self, text='Load').grid(column=4, row=0)
        ttk.Button(self, text='Save').grid(column=5, row=0, padx=10)

        self.c = tk.Canvas(self, width=21, height=21, highlightthickness=0, bg=color_hex)
        self.c.grid(column=2, row=0)
        
        ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Pencil', value=0, variable=self.root.tool).grid(row=1, column=0)
        ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Floodfill', value=1, variable=self.root.tool).grid(row=1, column=1)
        ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Eyedropper', value=2, variable=self.root.tool).grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2) # see here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainWindow()
    app.mainloop()
```

---

Or for this
[image]

you can add `sticky="w"` (w for west) in Canvas griding

```
self.c.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky="w")
```

Full Code

```py
import tkinter as tk
from string import hexdigits
from tkinter import ttk
from random import choices

color_hex = '#C91212'

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Main window')
        self.tool = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        self.topmenu = TopMenu(self)
        self.topmenu.pack()

class TopMenu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master: MainWindow):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.root = master
        ttk.Label(self, text="Hex color:").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)

        self.symbol_entry_text = tk.StringVar(value=color_hex)
        self.symbol_entry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.symbol_entry_text)
        self.symbol_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        ttk.Button(self, text='Random').grid(column=3, row=0, padx=10)
        ttk.Button(self, text='Load').grid(column=4, row=0)
        ttk.Button(self, text='Save').grid(column=5, row=0, padx=10)

        self.c = tk.Canvas(self, width=21, height=21, highlightthickness=0, bg=color_hex)
        self.c.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky="w")
        
        ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Pencil', value=0, variable=self.root.tool).grid(row=1, column=0)
        ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Floodfill', value=1, variable=self.root.tool).grid(row=1, column=1)
        ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Eyedropper', value=2, variable=self.root.tool).grid(row=1, column=2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainWindow()
    app.mainloop()
```